# Loose connection in Cooper night light receptacle

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have a Cooper / Eaton nightlight-receptacle TR7735W ([manufactuer](https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/products/wiring-devices-connectivity/receptacles.html), [amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007UNHHKG)), which I replaced a standard receptacle with. The receptacle is not at the end of the run, so there's a line out to the next receptacle, and is not switched.

[image: Night light]
<sub>(source: [cooperindustries.com](http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/dam/public/wiringdevices/products/images/t/TR7735W-220.jpg))</sub>

The old receptacle used the backstabs, but this new receptacle has the side screw plates. I wired the two hots to the two hot-side screws, the two neutrals to the one neutral-side screw (it has space for 2 wires), and the ground. I left the break-off tab intact. The switch and light work fine, and wiring is confirmed correct with my tester.

When I plugged in the vacuum, the light went off. I was able to get the light back on by pushing the vacuum plug to the side ever so slightly. Pushing it back the other way caused the light to turn off; I could repeat this to turn the light on or off repeatedly.

I admittedly haven't done any troubleshooting (didn't notice the problem with the vacuum plug until late), but is this indicative of a problem with the night light itself or just my wiring job? I'm thinking loose connection.

Comment: You mean when you plug into this outlet, or when you plug into the outlet this outlet feeds? Does the vacuum run when the light is off?

Comment: When I plug into this outlet. The vacuum did run when the light was off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those symptoms scream loose connection to me.

Turn off power, pull the unit out of the wall slightly, and tighten the connections.  My expectation is that during that you will find the underlying problem.  If not, exchange it for another one.

Comment: Pulled the unit out, nothing looked out of the ordinary, tightened the screws anyway. The light won't come on now. Put the old receptacle back in and gonna exchange the night light.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the vacuum runs with the light off, and that the light turns on and off as you move the vacuum plug in the receptacle part of this outlet, I don't think there's an external loose connection. - If there was, the vacuum would stop, too.

So, I think you have a defective "Outlet and NightLight in one device", with the defect/loose connection internal to the device. Return it.